# Stop logging parameters for django background tasks?

Tags: python, django

I'm using [Django Background Tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in my app for a task that requires user authentication. To create the task, I use a command like:

```
my_cool_task(pks, request.POST.get('username'), request.POST.get('password'))
```

I just realized that the `username` and `password` parameters are getting stored in the Django Admin tables for the tasks, which in this case creates a security issue.

Is there a way to not store these parameters? Or is there a better way to authenticate a process that will take longer than it takes for a server timeout error?

Comment: Are you using DRF?

Comment: You could customise the admin view to not show the parameters, but since they're parameters for the task they need to be *stored* somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @deceze - so I guess background tasks is not a good way to do things that need authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If the authentication is in your own system, then you can use the authentication to create the task. Only when a request is correctly authenticated it can create the task, so if it is not, then the task will not be created. That way you won't need to authenticate inside the task